# Drag and Drop jQuery Ajax Upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I need to upload files that were added via drag and drop, and to do this I need to use jQUery and Ajax. I have a form where the user can select files via a Browse button, but the user should be able to add files via drag and drop. I do not want to use a plugin.

The Javascript for the drag and drop works, but I don't know how to actually upload the file now (something with FileReader?). Here is the function (with validation code removed) that gets the dropped file.

```
function handleFileSelect(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

    for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        //i display the file name and do validation here
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to upload the files using jQuery's `.ajax` from here. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) to upload files via ajax.

```
var data = new FormData();  
...
data.append('file', files[i]);    
...
$.ajax({..., data: data, contentType: false, processData: false, type: 'POST', ...});
```

Comment: Googled "jQuery Ajax FormData" and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax. The top answer on that question works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial how to read the files client side:

[Drag and Drop](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Here is an example on how to upload the file.

[html5-file-upload-jquery-php](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)